# Bezier() not working

Tags: java, processing

I'm currently trying to write a drawing application. However, I keep getting an error.

This is the code I wrote:

```
void draw () {
    bezier(11, 11, 300, 60, 57, 551, 297, 543, 32, 43);
}
```

When I run this, it throws `The method bezier (float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float, float) in the type PApplet is not applicable for the arguments (int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int)`. When I remove `32, 43` it runs fine.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this the method you are trying to call? https://processing.org/reference/bezier_.html

If so, it takes 8 arguments... not 10. Which would explain why it works when you remove 32 and 43.

Comment: Silly me. Of couse, a 10 argument Bezier would be ill-specified; you need a integral number of control points. Compile error the OP gets is cryptic though.